# how to remove required highlights in HTML - Firefox

Tags: css, html, firefox

Is there any way to remove the red border from a required input or textarea in Firefox?
this is what i have tried:

HTML

```
<textarea class="opt" rows="3"placeholder="opt" required></textarea>
```

CSS

```
.opt:required:focus
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    outline:none;
}
```

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fqus7cd9/)

Comment: the red indicates invalid, which is sometimes exposed as ":invalid".  _!important_ can clobber anything

Comment: where is the rest of your code? What is adding the highlight?

Comment: @jmore009: there is no more code, the red is a userAgent style

Comment: I see, this is a firefox issue, chrome doesnt add red

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a `border`, it's a `box-shadow` and you can target `:invalid`:

```
.opt:invalid {
   box-shadow:none;
}
```

[**RUN IN FIREFOX**](http://jsfiddle.net/fqus7cd9/4/)

You can also add:

```
border: 1px solid black; //or whatever color/style you want
```

To overwrite the focus highlight as well:

[**RUN IN FIREFOX - 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/fqus7cd9/5/)

Comment: just a quick reminder that The `:invalid` selector is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.